# Installing operating system (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: hardware, raspberry-pi-os

[image]

Hi, I am trying to start a project and this is the first time I am using Raspberry Pi. I intend to create a retro gaming console, but I am unsure what kind of Operating system I should use. I see it gives an option to chose "Emulation and game OS", but again because I am new to this and am finding it difficult to find a documentation regarding the same.
Kindly help!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see.